# noun and verb usage interchangeably

Tags: grammar, word-choice, gerunds

In the following examples, the world "talk" was used as a verb and as a noun:

> I look forward to talk to you more soon, enjoy your day!

> I look forward to talking to you more soon, enjoy your day!

Which sentence is correct gramatically? If both are correct, what is the difference in the usage of talk vs talking in the previous two sentences?

Comment: Could you please not use backticks to set off quotes? Instead, use a `>` before the quoted sentence. Please take a look at your other questions I edited. Also, before asking a question here, make sure it hasn't been asked before by using the search function.

Answer (score 4):

Your second sentence is correct. **"Look forward to"** is a prepositional phrase and should be followed by a noun. Gerund is considered to be the noun form of a verb, so your sentence should be like this:

> I look forward to talking to you more soon, enjoy your day!

Answer (score 1):

I think that both your sentences use **talk** as a verb but according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/look-forward-to)

> **Look forward to** something means to be pleased or excited that it is
>   going to happen. The ‘to’ in look forward to is a preposition, so we
>   must follow it by a noun phrase or a verb in the -ing form

Comment: Exactly. The second sentence uses_talking_ as a gerund, so it's grammatically correct. To use _talk_ as a noun in the first sentence, however, it should probably employ an article or other determiner, e.g.: _I look forward to **another** talk **with** you soon, enjoy your day!_